# Adobe AIR apps on ios7 and ios8

Tags: games, adobe

Do I need any additional software to run games made from adobe AIR? Do they run as native apps?

Comment: Welcome to the site!  Do you mean that you wish to run existing AIR apps on iOS, or that you're a developer and you wish to publish AIR-based apps in the iTunes store?

Answer (score 1):

They run as normal apps. No extra effort is required on your part.